# asp.net ajax duplicating instead of loading partialview

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hey All im having an issue with ajax, im just trying to update a partial view but instead of the partial view being recreated its duplicating the whole page where the partial view is being shown from

controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult updatelist()
    {
        return PartialView("ForumTopicList");
    }
```

view

```
 using (Ajax.BeginForm("updatelist", "Forums", new AjaxOptions
 {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "topiclist"
        }))
 {
       <div>
    <input type="submit" value="refresh" />
</div>
 }   

 <div id="topiclist">
     @{Html.RenderPartial("ForumTopicList", this.Model.Topics);}
 </div>
```

hope its somehing obvious, thanks all

UPDATE: 
all im doing now is

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "topiclist" }))
 {
 <input type="submit" value="refresh" />
 }  

  <div id="topiclist">
 @{Html.RenderPartial("ForumTopicList", this.Model.Topics);}
 </div>
```

still just duplicates whole view once then both buttons of view and the duplicated view in div work fine :s

Comment: Looks like you have wrong names. `Ajax.BeginForm("updatelist")` will return `ForumTopicList` view. `Html.RenderPartial("ForumTopicList")` will return `ForumTopicList` as well. So, that's an expected behavior, I guess.

Comment: even if i change it to below it still shows a duplicate in the div , i should say it only duplicates once then the duplicate will update perfectly when the button is reclicked

 using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions
     {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,                                  UpdateTargetId = "topiclist"
            }))
     {